# C# : issue with file access control

Tags: c#, io, access-control

hi i have an issue with access control , i need to allow a file to be opened and executed but i want to prevent copying it to any other location , i tried all the filesystemrights but no luck i use that code to modify the access control

```
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
        FileSecurity ds = fi.GetAccessControl();
        ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users", FileSystemRights.xxxxxxxx, AccessControlType.Deny));
        fi.SetAccessControl(ds);
```

Comment: Ah the dream of DRM... Another person who don't understand that you can't differentiate copying and reading in the numerical world... (And even in the physical world it's damn hard to get right)

Comment: As far as I know you can't do that with the default windows file system. Depending on the file type you might create an executable that creates a temp file and opens that. Close the file after use.